# How to tell programmatically that an AWS Step Function execution has been completed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I am triggering a Step Function execution via a Python cell in a SageMaker Notebook, like this:

```
state_machine_arn = 'arn:aws:states:us-west-1:1234567891:stateMachine:alexanderMyPackageStateMachineE3411O13-A1vQWERTP9q9'
sfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
..
sfn.start_execution(**kwargs)  # Non Blocking Call
run_arn = response['executionArn']
print(f"Started run {run_name}. ARN is {run_arn}.")
```

and then in order to check that the execution (which might take hours to complete depending on the input) has been completed, before I start doing some custom post-analysis on the results, I manually execute a cell with:

```
response = sfn.list_executions(
    stateMachineArn=state_machine_arn,
    maxResults=1
)
print(response)
```

where I can see from the output the status of the execution, e.g. `'status': 'RUNNING'`.

How can I automate this, i.e. trigger the Step Function and continue the execution on my post-analysis custom logic only after the execution has finished? Is there for example a blocking call to start the execution, or a callback method I could use?

I can think of putting a sleep method, so that the Python Notebook cell would periodically call `list_executions()` and check the status, and only when the execution is completed, continue to rest of the code. I can statistically determine the sleep period, but I was wondering if there is a simpler/more accurate way.

---

PS: Related: [How to avoid simultaneous execution in aws step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878423/how-to-avoid-simultaneous-execution-in-aws-step-function), however I would like to avoid creating any new AWS resource, just for this, I would like to do everything from within the Notebook.

PPS: I cannot make any change to `MyPackage` and the Step Function definition.

Comment: If you don't want to create anything new (e.g. CloudWatch Event rule, lambda, etc), then pooling `list_executions` in a loop is your solution.

Comment: @Marcin you mean in a loop with a sleep method, right? Awesome, thank you so much, because that's my understand as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

If no new resources are to be created (no CloudWatch Event rules, lambda functions) nor any changes to existing Step Function are allowed, then **pooling iteratively** `list_executions` would be the best solution.

AWS CLI and boto3 have implemented similar solutions (not for Step Functions), but for some other services. They are called `waiters` (e.g. [ec2 waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters)). So basically you would have to create your own **waiter for Step Function**, as AWS does not provide one for that. AWS uses **15 seconds** sleep time from what I recall for its waiters.